# itextsharp read table

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've created a pdf with a table using itextsharp. I found an example at http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch05.html. Now I'd like to read data from the table again using itextsharp. I can't find any documentation on how to read this data. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Doesn't anybody have a good sample?

Comment: did you find a solution for reading table content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this in iTextSharp.  The section entitled ["Advanced: reading PDF" on the iTextSharp page](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch01.html) at SourceForge says:

> The pdf format is just a canvas where
>   text and graphics are placed without
>   any structure information. As such
>   there aren't any 'iText-objects' in a
>   PDF file. In each page there will
>   probably be a number of 'Strings', but
>   you can't reconstruct a phrase or a
>   paragraph using these strings. There
>   are probably a number of lines drawn,
>   but you can't retrieve a Table-object
>   based on these lines. In short:
>   parsing the content of a PDF-file is
>   NOT POSSIBLE with iText. Post your
>   question on the newsgroup
>   news://comp.text.pdf and maybe you
>   will get some answers from people that
>   have built tools that can parse PDF
>   and extract some of its contents, but
>   don't expect tools that will perform a
>   bullet-proof conversion to structured
>   text.

Comment: its been 5 years now. Is there any solution now to read table content from iTextSharp? any other library is ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to read the data from the PDF. What I ended up doing was converting the PDF to text and then string parse the result to get to the data.

In my scenario I wanted to take the data in the tables and convert them to Excel.