# How to read PDF file data in table format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have a PDF file that contains table Data. I have to read the PDF file in table format and insert the result into a database table.

Code to read PDF file in string format:

```
string strText = string.Empty;
try
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)Filename);

    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

        s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
        strText = strText + s;    
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Can anybody help me read the PDF file in table format?

Comment: Is the PDF a Tagged PDF or an ordinary PDF? If it is a Tagged PDF, it should be easy to extract the structure using iText's `TaggedPdfReaderTool`: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=281 If your PDF isn't tagged, you don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know what he's asking; the phrase “contains table Data” has too many possible meanings. Please elaborate and provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ITextSharp. As far as i know, ITextSharp does not support that operation. Check this link for more info;

[itextsharp read table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206454/itextsharp-read-table)

Comment: hi friend ,is any otherway to convert pdf file  into table format.